# How to add style function to features GeoJson to map the data?

Tags: python, leaflet, geojson, folium

I am new to Folium and I have an issue with the **style_function** parameter of **features.GeoJson**.

## My Code:

```py
# Initialization :
Map = folium.Map([40, -102], zoom_start = 3) 

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = data_gpd,
    data = data_gpd,
    columns = ['state', "pp_total_raw"],
    key_on = "feature.properties.state",
    fill_color='OrRd',
    fill_opacity=1,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Per-pupil total expenditure per locale",
    smooth_factor=0,
    Highlight= True,
    line_color = "Black",
    name = "States",
    show=False,
    overlay=True,
    nan_fill_color = "White",
).add_to(Map)


style = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#03fc94', 
                            'color':'#03fc94',
                            'fillOpacity': 0.1, 
                            'weight': 0.1}

folium.features.GeoJson(name="Click for Rural",
                        data=rural_gpd,
                        style_function=style,
                          show=True).add_to(Map)
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=True).add_to(Map)
Map
```

## Additional Informations :

**data_gpd** : is *GeoDataFrame* type of US state;

**rural_gpd** : is *GeoDataFrame* type some rural US state;

## Task:

I want to map the color of the states to the data values from *rural_gpd*.

I want also to update the horizontal legend (values and color).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of color do you want to add to the state? Also, can I share the data link for each geopandas? It's tough to explain and validate the code without the geopandas data.

Comment: @r-beginners , Thanks for the comment . So for the color i want it to be according to the value of the 'pp_total_raw', so i won't to make it the same for all  states, so i want to make the style for example from orange to red i.e (form low to high value of  'pp_total_raw'). And yes i appreciate sharing the data link.